# ASP.NET Pagination display using DataReader

Tags: c#, asp.net, pagination

I have a list of around 30 records to display on a page, and ideally I only want to show 5 at a time, requiring some kind of pagination.

I am using a datareader to construct the html to display via a literal as seen below:

```
currentLiteral.Text += "<div class=\"row\"><div class=\"twoColumnOne\"><img src=\"image/" + (dReader["image"].ToString()) +" \"alt=\"" + (dReader["name"].ToString()) + "\"/></div>"
                        + "<div class=\"twoColumnTwo\"><h3>" + (dReader["name"].ToString()) + "</h3><h5>" + (dReader["location"].ToString()) + "</h5><p>" + (dReader["description"].ToString()) + "</p></div>"
                        + "<div class=\"clearFloat\"></div></div>";
```

Is there a way I can achieve pagination with this?

Answer (score 1):

Use a GridView for paging:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gView" runat="server" 
 AllowPaging="true" PageSize="5" AutoGenerateColumns="true" />
```

Code behind:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Load(dReader);
gView.DataSource = dt;
gView.DataBind();
```

You can also specify the names of your columns beforehand (in the markup), but this code will just name the columns as whatever they are in the data reader.